# search and replace numbers in vim

Tags: vim, regular-expression

I have a sql dump file that includes entries like this:

```
INSERT INTO "widgets" VALUES(152,'12477','abc@gmail.com','smtp','Jerry Jo',0);
INSERT INTO "widgets" VALUES(153,'12477','36542','sip','Jerry Jo',0);
INSERT INTO "widgets" VALUES(158,'92865','me@gmail.com','smtp','Jane Jo',0);
```

I want to search and replace "VALUES(XXX," with "VALUES(DEFAULT,"
The number that currently follows the word values can be up to 5 digits long.

So far, I've been playing around with the following commands similar to:

```
 :%s/\<(VALUES(\d+\>,/VALUES(DEFAULT,/g
```

But I can't seem to get it right. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @Theophrastus can you show me what you mean?

Comment: @Theophrastus that's failing.  It gives me a pattern not found error message

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the *very magic* `\v` flag to make the regex more like `perl` and less like `vim` (which thus requires that the `(` be escaped but on the plus side `\d+` matches):

```
:%s/\vVALUES\(\d+/VALUES(DEFAULT
```